# How to send xml data in request in JSP?

Tags: xml, jsp, servlets

I need to send my request as a xml to servlet from jsp. how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Two ways (in case by 'jsp' you mean 'from the browser'):

- with form submit - with a `<form method="post" action="..">`. You will have to prepare the XML (with javascript for example) and set it in a field a request parameter, then parse the request parameter on the servlet
- with ajax - using [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) or a framework like jQuery. With it you can submit anything.